# reactjs dropdown parent menu routing not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router, router, tailwind-css

I have created a router for dropdown child menu as like

```
<Route path="/setup" component={Setup}>
     <Route path="/setup/:employee" component={Employee}/>
     <Route path="/setup/:company" component={Company}/>
     <Route path="/setup/:user" component={User}/>
</Route>
```

when i use `/setup/employee` only it will work but parent menu `/setup` and other child menu not work not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, It doesn't need to add Route as a child to another one. Change your `Route` component same as bellow:

```
 <Route path="/setup" component={Setup}/>
 <Route path="/setup/:employee" component={Employee}/>
```

In addition, this approach of using routes doesn't work. Assume that you would like to open `/setup/1`, because of using `/setup/:employee` above of the `/setup/:company` and `/setup/:user` router just understand the first one. You couldn't route to the address with other parameters. How `router` can understand what have you sent? An employee or company or user? You should change the other routes. You can just have a route style with parameter once.
But if you would like to do something in this way, you can create a route such as:

```
<Route path="/setup/:component/:page" component={MyCustomComponent}/>
```

And implement `MyCustomComponent` component same as bellow:

```
function MyCustomComponent() {
  let { component, page } = useParams();
  switch (component) {
    case "FirstChild":
      return <FirstChild page={page} />;
    case "SecondCHild":
      return <SecondChild page={page} />;
    default:
      return <NoneOfChildren />;
  }
}
```

Finally, these are the Child components:

```
function NoneOfChildren(){
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Nothing have been sent as page!</h3>
    </div>
  );
}

function SecondChild(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Second Page: {props.page}</h3>
    </div>
  );
}

function FirstChild(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>First Page: {props.page}</h3>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit React Router - URL Parameters (forked)]

Comment: thanks problem is fixed but i have more child menus added on router it won't work. please check my questions (updated*)

Comment: @shawn Move all of the child out of the parent `Router`.

Comment: @shawn I updated the answer. Please check it again.

Comment: it won't work. i have updated to top on parent router

Comment: @shawn You mean with one child it work but with more than children it doesn't work?

Comment: yes only one child is work but another not work with your updated code

Comment: nope i didn't get any error. but it works only one child

Comment: @shawn Actually this approach of using routes doesn't work. Assume that you would like to open `/setup/1`, because of using `/setup/:employee` above of the `/setup/:company` and `/setup/:user` router just understand the first one. You couldn't route to the address with other parameters. How router can what have you sent? An employee or company or user? You should change the other routes. You can just have a route style with parameter once.

Comment: so how can i set this router in reactjs? i have 10+ child menu in setup menu. so i want these router as like `/setup/company` , `/setup/user`,  `/setup/etc`

Comment: oaky @Majid Mohammadi thanks for your time

Comment: @shawn Your welcome. Just before I update the answer, Are the parameters which you're sending it id or something like that ? I mean `employee`,`user` or `company` is a id?

Comment: employee, company, user etc is Setup pages child menu. Every menu is each page name in each component. @Majid

Comment: @shawn I think the method I've used is convenient for your aim. Please try it and if there was any problem, leave a comment for further contribution.

Comment: I fixed this issues just use like these `/setup/employee` , `setup/company` on routes

Comment: Happy to hear that.

Comment: @shawn Yes, I think I didn't understand the exactly what would you like to do. So You just remove the parameters and use the route with component with together.